# Vuejs testing with Mocha: component not mounting to element

Tags: testing, vue.js, mocha.js, vuejs2, jsdom

I'm relatively new to developing with VueJS and testing with Mocha (being used headlessly) and I'm intentionally not using vue-cli to get a better understanding of how everything works. I have a suit of unit tests that function fairly well (fetch requests, getting/setting props, etc), up until the point where I need to check something in the DOM. It appears that the components are being successfully created, but they are not being mounted to an element.

I'm using JSDom to create a DOM context for the headless tests, as can be seen in my _setup.js:

```
global.Vue = require('vue/dist/vue');
require('jsdom-global')('<html><head></head><body><main id="MyApp"></main></body>');
```

In these cases, $el is undefined, despite the fact the above-defined DOM elements can be found:

app.spec.js

```
import assert from 'assert';
import app    from '../src/js/app.vue';

describe('app.vue', function() {
  describe('#created', function() {
    it('should initialize the application', function() {  
      const vEl = document.getElementById('MyApp');
      const vm = new Vue({el: vEl}).$mount();

      console.log(vEl);    // HTMLElement {}
      console.log(vm.$el); // undefined

      assert(true); // pass anyway for now
    });
  });
});
```

myComp.spec.js:

```
import assert from 'assert';
import header from '../src/js/components/myComp.vue';

describe('myComp.vue', function() {
  describe('#created', function() {
    it('should initialize the component', function() {
      const Constructor = Vue.extend(myComp);
      const comp = new Constructor({
        propsData: {
          someProp: 'hello world'
        }
      }).$mount();

      console.log(document.getElementById('MyApp')); // HTMLElement {}
      console.log(comp.$el)                          // undefined

      assert(true);
    });
  });
});
```

Note that if I change the element's ID to something that doesn't exist when doing getElementById, I get the following error - which to me it would imply that it has a handle on the element when using the correct ID:

> // document.getElementById('IDontExist');
> [Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.

Note that my component definition is a little different since I'm going for a bare-bones approach and not using vue-cli. Examples (some code omitted for brevity):

app.vue

```
import myComp from './components/myComp.vue';

let app = new Vue({
  el: '#MyApp',
  data: {
    someProp: 'hello world'
  },
  created: function() {},
  methods: {}
});

export {app};
```

myComp.vue

```
export default Vue.component('my-comp', {
  props: ['someProp'],
  data: function() {},
  created: {},
  watch: {},
  methods: {},
  template: `<div>{{someProp}}</div>`
});
```

I have a feeling I'm overlooking something pretty simple regarding how to wire up the component mounting to the DOM, *or* accessing the component (but it seems to be in line with the [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/unit-testing.html#Writing-Testable-Components)). Any ideas?

Comment: I am having the same issue.. regardless of using jsDom or jsdom-global and no luck. Using mocha, mocha-webpack, typescript, vue-loader, ts-loader